# Why after installing MacPorts the kernel_task RAM size raised x1.5?

Tags: install, macports, kernel, kernel-extensions

I noticed that before installing MacPorts the `kernel_task` RAM usage was about 200-300 Mb. After installing that the process is **using 482.5 Mb real RAM**. What are the components (maybe .kexts, which then?) MacPorts has added to the kernel_task process?